# ubuntu touch web app url, sub domain

Tags: ubuntu-touch

ive got this working now but have a problem with sub domains 
specially if they can change for instance

yourwebsite.com

user clicks on there profile which could be

wayne.yourwebsite.com

but for john it could be

john.yourwebsite.com

how do i make this work

for instance i tried http://*.yourwebsite.com as a web pattern

but the wildcard doesnt work

the subdomain could be a number of domains so im not sure how to accept
anything subdomain it just opens a web browser

Wayne

Comment: Actually, the wildcard is supposed to work. Could you please post all your .desktop entry?

Comment: Name=BandCamp
Comment=webapp for BandCamp
Type=Application
Icon=BandCamp.png
Exec=webapp-container --enable-back-forward --store-session-cookies --webappUrlPatterns=https?://bandcamp.com/* https?://*.bandcamp.com http://bandcamp.com/* http://bandcamp.com %u
Terminal=false
X-Ubuntu-Touch=true

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should change `https?://*.bandcamp.com` to `https?://*.bandcamp.com/*` on your webappUrlPatterns.